# How to match two segmentation masks with translation, rotation and/or scale adjustment

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have two images taken from slightly different positions. After performing image segmentation on these, I would like to match the segmentation masks of the two images so that I can identify the same objects in both. Most of the time the sizes or orientations of objects change:

[image]
[image]

Sometimes objects that appear in one image do not appear in the other, for example:

[image]
[image]

I've tried naively matching individual objects using their centroid positions and sizes, but it's very error prone. What's the best way to do this using, e.g. OpenCV?

Comment: the basic issue is object tracking through video. there are simple solutions with limited success, and there are advanced solutions. since it seems that you are annotating, it's actually your task to determine object identity. look into CVAT for video annotation: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a RANSAC-like approach. The transformation is not much skewed so you could just try a similarity transformation (translation + rotation + scaling). This only takes two corresponding point pairs. From two matched pairs, you compute the transformation, transform the other points and see how well they match.

As your number of points is small, an exhaustive search with all possible pairs (N(N-1)/2 of them) is not excessive. (And it seems that you can sort the points left to right without introducing inversions, which will reduce the number of possibilities.)

Comment: Using two matched pairs to compute the transformation is a good idea, but I would need to somehow find two pairs of objects matched with high confidence without looking at the images, since I'm hoping to do this completely automatically.

Comment: @rferdinand: I am not sure you understood my answer. This method deals with that.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean now. I'd have to try all combinations of point pairs and see which produces the best transformation for all the other points. A little time consuming for the more complex images, but certainly worth a try. Thanks!

Comment: @rferdinand: you may find some tricks to avoid the exhaustive comparison. (I mentioned one.)

Comment: It's a little tricky since sometimes inversions do happen because of parallax, but I can skip over pairs where the size discrepancy is too large.

Comment: @rferdinand: you know better than me.